# AngularJS: Trying to set seleted in ng-options and output value, not whole object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with ng-options, I don't really understand them! However as I read the documentation I was wondering if you can help.

I have a simple object array in my controller like so...

```
$scope.childrenType = [
            {
                label: 'None',
                value: -1
            },
            {
                label: 'Son',
                value: 0
            },
            {
                label: 'Daughter',
                value: 1
            },
            {
                label: 'Step Son',
                value: 2
            },
            {
                label: 'Step Daughter',
                value: 3
            }
        ];
```

I use this to populate a select menu in my view...

```
<select data-ng-model="child.type"
        data-ng-options="type.label for type in childrenType track by type.value"
        data-clean-up-select>
<br>
What is selected: {{ child.type }}
```

The directive 'data-clean-up-select' just removed the empty option we get with `ng-options`. Now I want to do two things, I want to pre-select the select default value (from data that comes from a service but for simplicity we will set it here like so)

```
$scope.child.type = 2;
```

Now the default value is not selected (I want Step Son to be selected in this example) and on change I only want the value to be the value, integer not the whole object of the `ChildrenType`.

So when I change the menu I want the value to just be `1` or `3`, etc... and not `{"label":"Daughter","value":1}`

I have prepared a JSBin to demonstrate my problem...

Here is a JsBin: https://jsbin.com/liwoko/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your ng-option like this :

```
<select data-ng-model="child.type"
        data-ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in childrenType"
        data-clean-up-select>
<br>
```

Before the `as`, you have the value store on your model. If you want just the value, `type.value` will do the trick.
And because you save just the value on your `ng-model`. Your previous initialisation on Step brother will be fine too.

Moreover, in this situation you don't need to use `track by`. The "as part" of your options already do this job.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select data-ng-model="child.type"
        data-ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in childrenType"
        data-clean-up-select>
<br>
What is selected: {{ child.type }}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<select ng-model="child"
        ng-options="item.label for item in childrenType"
        data-clean-up-select></select>
<br>
{{child.value}}
```

and in your javascript

```
$scope.childrenType = [
        {label : 'None', value : -1},
        {label : 'Son', value : 0},
        {label : 'Daughter', value : 1},
        {label : 'Step Son', value : 2},
        {label : 'Step Daughter', value : 3}
    ];

    $scope.child = $scope.childrenType[3];
```

Comment: This will solve the init problem. But the still, the all object will be put on the model.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do change this from

```
  Child Type is: {{ child.type }}
```

to

```
  Child Type is: {{ child.type.label }}
```